# Add an error page to this express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building an express app, a basic twitter interface.

I want to add an error page to the application, so that if anything goes wrong with the routes the user will see a friendly message rendered, instead of the default error code.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
//Tell app to render template
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    if(!error){
        res.render('index', {
            myName: myName,
            profileImage: profileImage,
            screenName: screenName,
            followerCount: followerCount,
            dateTweeted: dateTweeted,
            tweetContent: tweetContent,
            noOfRetweets: noOfRetweets,
            noOfLikes: noOfLikes,
        });       
    }
});
```

Why can't I just do this?

```
else{
    res.send('sorry, bro, page not found!);
}
```

Or do I need to do something with passing the error to the 'next’ handler? I can't get my head around how that works.

Would really appreciate some help please!

Comment: http://www.hacksparrow.com/express-js-custom-error-pages-404-and-500.html

Comment: Your written code  doesn't give any sense. How will you get error value?And you will come to know when you get error while manipulating anything in your code

Comment: I'm a bit lost :(

Comment: How do you get all the mentioned values  myName: myName,
            profileImage: profileImage,
            screenName: screenName,
            followerCount: followerCount,
            dateTweeted: dateTweeted,
            tweetContent: tweetContent,
            noOfRetweets: noOfRetweets,
            noOfLikes: noOfLikes,

Comment: That's in the rest of my requests, the above code is nested within that

Answer (score 0):

> Your question is not very specific but I assume you will get some errors during manipulation.

Then you can send type of error like this after getting error

```
//Tell app to render template
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if ("not error") {
//You can do whatever you want
   res.status(200).send({message:"Success message"})
    }else{//If error you can choose your error code with relevant message
      res.status(400).send({message:"Bad request error"});
                //OR
      res.status(404).send({message:"Not found error"});
                //OR
      res.status(401).send({message:"Unauthorization error"});
                //OR
      res.send(500).send({message:"Any server side erorr"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom `middleware`that does this for you...

```js
function errorMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  // implement some logic, do your check...
  let thereAreErrors = /* ? */ false;

  if(!thereAreErrors) {
    return next();
  }

  return res.status(400).end();
}

function indexRouteCtrl(req, res) {
  return res.render('index');
}

app.get('/'/, errorMiddleware, indexRouteCtrl);
```